# Is there an way to run a command into terminal that linked to package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

**Task**

> Build a program to analyze app usage data for a hypothetical menu planning calendar app. On any day, a user can plan multiple meals, and each meal may have multiple dishes. The program you build will analyze how engaged users are with the app

**Data**

> In the ./data folder, you will find a bunch of files in the form userId.json. They contain app data for a bunch of users. The structure should be fairly obvious upon examination.

**Output**

> `./dist/run active 2016-09-01 2016-09-08` should result in a list of
> comma- separated user ids that were “active” during the specified
> period, where “active” means they had at least 5 meals.
>
> `./dist/run superactive 2016-09-01 2016-09-08` should result in a list
> of comma- separated user ids that were “super-active” during the
> specified period, which means they had more than 10 meals.
>
> `./dist/run bored 2016-09-01 2016-09-08` should result in a list of
> comma- separated user ids that were “bored” during the specified
> period, meaning that they were “active” in the preceding period, but
> didn’t make the “active” threshold in the specified period.

**Note: I just added Task & Data section for having better idea about the task i have been asked to do. How can i add something (some scripts) into `package.json` that will hit and do the rest job for me whenever above three command (e.g. `./dist/run active 2016-09-01 2016-09-08`) will be run on terminal.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to run a script inside `package.json` that executes `./dist/run active 2016-09-01 2016-09-08` (or any of the other 2 scripts) PLUS other commands.

**This answer assumes you run a bash environment, such as Linux, MacOS or WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)**

One idea is to put your execution inside a `Shell` script for each flow (say `active` for example) and then have each as a separate command on `package.json`. Something like this:

*File `active.sh`*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./dist/run active 2016-09-01 2016-09-08

echo "Put some other logic here as well"
```

*File `package.json`*

```
...
{
  "scripts": {
    "active": "./active.sh"
  }
}
...
```

**Note**

Make sure that your `.sh` file has the correct permissions to execute

```
chmod +x ./active.sh
```

**Note 2**

The `#!/usr/bin/env bash` on the `.sh` file is called a [Shebang (or hash bang)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

---

Finally, you can execute your flow by doing:

```
npm run active
```

And repeat the process for your other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

in package.json you can define scripts.

```js
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "static": "some comand"
  },
```

then you can type, `npm run static`. After this, it will run the **some command** in the current directory.